# Trying to get text using getText() method with Selenium and Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, selenium

Trying to get text using **getText()** method with Selenium and Javascript but not having luck.

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver');


(async function example() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
    try {
        // Navigate to webscraper.io
        await driver.get('https://webscraper.io/test-sites');

        // Scrape links
        let links = await driver.findElements(By.xpath('//*[@class="row test-site"]/div/h2/a'))
        
        // loop through links and print
        console.log('\nFound ' + links.length + ' Links total.\n')
        
        var link;
        for (link of links) {
            console.log(link.getText());
            };
    }
    finally{
        driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

Here are the errors i'm getting.

```
Found 7 Links total.

Promise { <pending> }
(node:92934) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:62579
    at ClientRequest.<anonymous>
'''
```

Answer (score 0):

had to change to change the following code :

**from:**
*console.log(link.getText());*

**to:**
*console.log(await link.getText());*

All it needed was the **await**